# Execute Stored Procedure with less Input Parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which needs 4 parameters to execute. But I want to execute it with passing only 3 parameters. How can I achieve that?

For example: my stored procedure usually executes like this.

```
EXEC usp_my_sp @fname = 'Sandeep', 
               @lname = 'Kumar', 
               @age = '26', 
               @city = 'New Delhi'**
```

It will return all people named `Sandeep Kumar`, Age = 26 and living in `New Delhi`.

But I want to get all people named `Sandeep Kumar` of age 26, from all cities. Here I need to omit the 4th parameter.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 3):

Create parameters that have null default values, and write your Where clause predicates with `coalesce()`, (or `IsNUll()`).

```
 Create procedure MySP
    @fName varchar(50) = null,
    @lName varchar(50) = null,
    @age byte = null,
    @city varchar(30) = null
 as
        Select -- stuff
        From MyTable
        Where firstName = coalesce(@fName, firstName )
          and lastName = coalesce(@lName, LastName)
          and City = coalesce(@city , City )
          and lastName = coalesce(@lName, LastName)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a catch-all query with dynamic search conditions.

The basic non-optimized solution is to change the `where` clause for `@city` to be something like this (`t` being the alias for your table):

```
where (t.city = @city or @city is null)
```

Some also write this as

```
where t.city = isnull(@city,t.city)
```

Both options will return the correct result set, but for a procedure this can lead to issues of a cached plan being sub-optimal for a given set of parameters. There are a few solutions to improve this situation, the simplest being to add `option(recompile)` to the end of the query. This will generate a new query plan for each call to the procedure, and thus incur some additional overhead with each execution.

A more complex solution would rewrite the query using dynamic sql, and for that I will direct you to the following resources:

catch-all query reference:

- [An Updated "Kitchen Sink" Example - Aaron Bertand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/)
- [Dynamic Search Conditions - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)
- [Catch-all queries - Gail Shaw](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)
- [Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the RECOMPILE Options - Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options)